# UIPickerView custom view don't visualizate

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uipickerview

I have custom view:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface materialView : UIView {
    IBOutlet UIImageView * _img;
    IBOutlet UILabel * _title;
}
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)pTitle image:(UIImage *)pImage;
@end
```

and

```
#import "materialView.h"
@implementation materialView
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)pTitle image:(UIImage *)pImage {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 295, 38);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [_img setImage:pImage];
        [_title setText:pTitle];
    }
return self;
}
@end
```

then I add this View to my UIPickerView:

```
- (id)init {
    self=[super init];
    if (self) {
        materialView * pl = [[materialView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Plastic" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aaa.jpeg"]];
        materialView * gl = [[materialView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Glass" image:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"bbb.jpeg"]];
        _loadedItems = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pl, gl, nil] retain];
    } 
return self;
}
...

pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.delegate = self;
...

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    return [_loadedItems objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Problem is, that I have quite strange behavior. My View don't show in Picker View.
Can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component
           reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

test that `_loadedItews` and the objects returned with `objectAtIndex:` are not `nil`? Your code looks reasonable otherwise without more context.

Also set your custom view's userInteractionEnabled property to NO. It seems that if it is set to YES then custom views intercept the touches and the picker can't scroll to the tapped row.

Comment: I believe, that this should do PickerViewDelegate with pickerView: viewForRow: forComponent: reusingView:
isn't true?

Comment: 2 petert. Thanks, you are right. I should add my ImageVie and Label to custom View during Init. I've created .xib file, and was strong convinced< that I've related my class with this .xib.

Comment: A re-read of the question is clearer, though consider how you tag your question in future.